# Video frame freezed on next frame HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a basic HTML5 video player which have a Prev/Next frame button (one for each action).
When I play the video, it does normally showing all the frames, but when I pause for example in 45th frame, when I click Next frame, it shows on screen the number 55th.

I can still clicking next until it arrives to 55th frame and it shows the same freezed frame.

It happens the same if I pause on 45th and click next. It shows the freezed frame and if I play the video, it shows the freezed frame until the shown frame, but I can listen the audio correctly.

The video it's 25fps and I do the next:

```
video = $("#VideoContainer_videoPlayer")[0];
sumador = 1/25;

$("#nextFrame").click(function () {
  video.pause();

  video.currentTime = video.currentTime + sumador;

});
```

Edit:

The video codecs I tried are:

H264 + AAC 1,5Mb bitrate (4,1Mb)
AVC + AAC 1,5Mb bitrate (4,1Mb)

Both are the same video converted from an Apple ProRes 422 HQ

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I've reprocessed the video to 4.0Mb bitrate and it doesn't freeze the frames anymore.